# How to justify flying fish actually flying?

Tags: evolution

I want to make flying fish, a gliding creature, evolve into fish that actually fly.  How should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, you'll need:

- The ability to breathe air.
- The impetus to leave the water for longer periods, either to hunt or
  evade predators.
- A better wing structure. The breathing part will be the hardest. In truth, once they can breathe air for extended periods (which they would need to do for actual flight) the wings are relatively easy--I say this because different evolutionary paths have caused flight.

Take a look at the BBC documentary [THE FUTURE IS WILD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Future_Is_Wild) one of the episodes that take place 200 million years in the future cover flish.

Answer (score 1):

As @ErinThursby has already said, extensive evolutionary changes would be needed to get a modern flying fish up where you want to go.

As an alternative, abandon the current flying fish and start again with this [other bird-like fish](http://www.durhamregion.com/news-story/6385420-bird-like-fish-emerges-from-the-deep-atlantic-ocean/).
This fish appears to be well on its way to having the right bone and muscle structures needed for wings.  With this start and a strong evolutionary motivator such as [the introduction of a major new predator](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/50853/edestus-gigantus-in-modern-oceans), you only need to teach the critter to [breath air](http://aquaristmagazine.com/air-breathing-fish-a-comprehensive-guide-to-anabantoids/) and the skies will be filled with scales.